# Can't connect react container to node container using container name

Tags: reactjs, node.js, docker, docker-compose, cors

I want to create connection between react(frontend) container and node(backend) container using container name.

react(frontend) dockerfile:

```
> FROM node:18-alpine as builder WORKDIR /frontend-docker-example/
> EXPOSE 3000
> 
> COPY package*.json /frontend-docker-example/ RUN npm install COPY
> public/ /frontend-docker-example/public 
> COPY src/ /frontend-docker-example/src 
> CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

node(backend) dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /backend-docker-example/
EXPOSE 5000

COPY package*.json /backend-docker-example/
RUN npm install
COPY app.js  /backend-docker-example/app.js
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  #Frontend Service
  client:
    container_name: client
    build: 
      context: ./client
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - server

  server:
    container_name: server
    build: 
      context: ./server
```

react code:

```
const response = await fetch('http://server:5000/add',{ .... }
```

Node code:

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: '*'
}))
```

Error:

```
POST http://server:5000/add net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Both container are in same network as used docker compose. for surity i also checked both container ip using docker inspect. Also checked DNS resolution. `docker exec -it react-frontend sh` and then `ping server`
i can successfully ping and curl both and got response but can not on localhost. How can i solve this?

Comment: The `fetch()` call is running in the end user's browser.  The browser isn't in a container and can't use Docker networking features.  In the linked question I describe a couple of alternative approaches, including a reverse-proxy approach that doesn't need a host name at all.

Answer (score 0):

> can not on localhost

For server docker-compose ports, add this: `- '127.0.0.1:5000:5000'`

You are exposing docker image port, but you also need to expose docker-compose network port.

Comment: i tried this, but getting same error "POST http://server:5000/add net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" as i am doing http reuqest for container name.

Comment: From localhost, you don't have `server` DNS resolution like from container (provided by the docker-compose networking resources).

you need to do `POST 127.0.0.1:5000/add`